# What is the correct frequency of changing content regularly?

Tags: seo

What is the correct frequency of changing content regularly? Suppose I have a site "Seven Sea" having 5 links name as Home, About Us, Product, Sitemap, Contact Us. It is good for site to change the site content regularly. But is there is any minimum and maximum frequency for do this job. Suppose I do change my content daily then is that good for SEO point of view. OR suppose I change my content once in a year Is that bad for SEO. 
What is best or more better choice?

A REQUEST:
If this type of question already answered then give me that answered link and do not close the question.

Answer (score 4):

You're thinking about it in the wrong way: it's about providing value and quality, not meeting a quota. There is no magic frequency.

You should update your content as often as **you** need to to keep your site in step with what **your visitors** want. For a tech blog, that's probably several times a day; for a site that sells boutique guitar amplifiers, it might be more like once a month or less.

The point is it's about relevancy to your visitors (or potential visitors). If the boutique guitar amplifier site updated as often as the tech blog, the odds are that content would be worthless, because his business doesn't move that fast.

Focus on meeting your users needs, ideally with some flair and personality, and you won't go far wrong.

Comment: Respected G Dav Sir, very helpful answer. Thank You.